# Gamemaker Studio 2: My character won’t transition through rooms

Tags: game-engine, game-maker, gml, game-maker-language, game-maker-studio-2

I use transition code that I learned through a Udemy course, but the character in my game will only transition through the first door, and no others.

I am using the same object but changing the creation code of the object. I use variables `room_`, `start_`. I use these to select different rooms and start positions within the creation code. Click the link to view video game - (https://drive.google.com/open?id=1jCWIM3hYymgspW54EPbnUDrNQVZbY_4B).

Comment: Hi there, unfortunate uploading your whole project isn't very helpful as it's only accesible for those having Gamemaker Studio. Even then, just showing a few parts of the code, like in this case, the code how you made your transition, would be more helpful to us. :)

Comment: Is the character a persistent object or you create it every time in every different new?

Comment: Upload some code to help us answer the question more efficiently. It isn’t helpful at the moment to download the whole game.

Answer (score 0):

I fiddled with the project a bit, I understand the error you're getting, after the character goes through the first door, he can't go back even though in r_sworld there's the same type of doors, they all have collision masks, they all have variables... I don't know why your code wasn't working, but I found a solution!

Move the code **from o_player::o_door to o_player::step**.
Using collision events in GMS is generally not advised, you should try to do as much in the step event as you can. You can replace your collision event with o_door by adding this at the end of your step event:

```
if (place_meeting(x, y, o_door)) {
    var door = instance_place(x, y, o_door);
    room_goto(door.room_);
    global.player_start_position = door.start_;
    persistent = true;
}
```

Here's a catch. If the new position dictated by `global.player_start_position` makes the player appear on top of some other door in the destination room, you will be immediately teleported back to the first room. Make sure the coordinates in `door.start_` are never too close to other doors.

Hope this helps!