# Gamemaker Studio 2: My character isn't transitioning properly throughout rooms

Tags: game-maker

I've followed a specific course by Aidan (as shown here: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=evkFHHNp0-Q&list=PLwG2Q399ulV3TyEWodJYrje3KsxvIxBv1) for my Gamemaker Studio 2 video game, and I didn't have any issues until I realized when I reentered a room my character disappeared? My character normally transitions from Room1 to Room2 pretty easily, but when I want to go back to Room 2 from Room 1, the character isn't there. I tried rewatching videos where he explains "warp points" as well as his other videos, and the solution to my issue doesn't seem to come up. 
I set my character to "persistent" by setting it in the creation code to be true, as well as check-marking the box on the actual object, but it still doesn't work. Any help would be greatly appreciated!

EDIT: I realize there is a similar question another user asked([Gamemaker Studio 2: My character won’t transition through rooms](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53647606/gamemaker-studio-2-my-character-won-t-transition-through-rooms?rq=1)), and I tried doing what they suggested but it still doesn't seem to be working. I don't think the issue is that the character won't transition through the rooms, I believe that it can't transition multiple times without something going wrong.

Comment: Can you add the link to the other user's answer in the body of your question?

Comment: @C.Lewis I edited it so you can see the link :)

Comment: Can you remove the 'persistent' setting on the characters creation code? I think that's unnecessary. Perhaps it might be better to make a 3rd room, and check if it's swapping correctly between room 2 and 3, if it's not working, then the issue is the transition, and if it does work, then the issue is the starting location.

Comment: @Steven thank you for your help, I'll try that!